# How to solve 'Unhandled Promise Rejection: Error: Unable to resolve bare specifier "app.js" from http://localhost:3000/'

Tags: javascript, typescript, systemjs

I have been studying typescript.
I am encountering the below error while studying node modules.

[image]

Clicking on the anonymous function take me to the below code.

[image]

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Learning TypeScript</title>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        System.import('app.js')
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the link to my [demo project](https://github.com/anirudha-music/Study-TypeScript/tree/02_using_type_for_better_code)

Comment: the demo project link is a bit wrong

Comment: can you try in your tsconfig.ts to add the files directive pointing to the systemjs file

Comment: Can you please change my code and do pull request, please beacuse I am actually an iOS Developer. Switching to backend so I don't know much about this. Thanks

Comment: but Id suggest not putting the systemjs file into the node modules folder since that should be deletable and recreatable by doing npm install

Comment: Okay I'll try to do what you are saying.

Comment: and since it already is a js file you can just put it in the output folder of the ts compile (create a copy first im not sure the ts compile will clear the fodler) and reference it by ./system.js in you index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using newest version of `SystemJS`. You have to make some change:

- `index.html`: use  `System.import('./app.js')` instead of `System.import('app.js')` // hmm
- `tsconfig.json`: use `"module": "system"` instead of `"module": "commonjs"`.
- `app.ts`: use `import { PI, calculateCircumference } from "./maths/circle.js";` instead of `import { PI, calculateCircumference } from "./maths/circle";` // hmm

(I can not find a way to config `baseUrl` or `defaultExtension`)

Run `tsc` command to rebuild `app.js` file before you reload html page on browser.

Comment: I did what you suggested now I this errors `[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:3000/maths/circle`, `Refused to execute http://localhost:3000/maths/circle as script because "X-Content-Type: nosniff" was given and its Content-Type is not a script MIME type.`, `Unhandled Promise Rejection: Error: Error loading http://localhost:3000/maths/circle from http://localhost:3000/app.js`

Comment: @AnirudhaMahale The third item:  `use import { PI, calculateCircumference } from "./maths/circle.ts";` instead of `import { PI, calculateCircumference } from "./maths/circle";` // hmm

Comment: Yes If I do that then `tsc` doesn't compile with an [Error](https://i.imgur.com/Ij7mT2m.png)

Comment: Can you do pull request of my code. That will be very helpful for me.

Comment: @AnirudhaMahale ohh, I am sorry, `.js` instead of `.ts`

Comment: Thanks a lot, This seems to work, Can you just update your answer I'll mark it as correct and upvote it.